# Mongo query security issue?

Tags: mongodb

I've create an interesting API and I'm wondering if there is a security issue I haven't thought of. So basically my get route allows the user to send an entire stringified mongo query, which I then just pass to the mongo driver.

I make sure that any query containing $where or function are invalid. Other then that I couldn't think of any other issue I might run in to by allowing the client to send queries.

I'm really interested to hear your thoughts, am I missing something totally obvious here?